# When I try to get a number from a string of characters, the function always returns zero

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, char

EDIT: So it looks like the problem is that the string that getNum is supposed to convert to a float is not actually a string containing all the characters of the token.  Instead it contains the character immediately following the token, which is usually NaN so the atof converts it to 0.  I'm not sure why this behavior is occuring.

I'm working on a scanner + parser that evaluates arithmetic expressions.  I am trying to implement a method that gets a token (stored as a string) which is a number and turns it into a float, but it always returns 0 no matter what the token is.

I was given the code for a get_character function, which I am not sure is correct. I'm having a little trouble parsing what's going on with it though, so I'm not sure:

```
int get_character(location_t *loc)
{
    int rtn;
        if (loc->column >= loc->line->length) {
        return 0;
    }
    rtn = loc->line->data[loc->column++];
    if (loc->column >= loc->line->length && loc->line->next) {
        loc->line = loc->line->next;
        loc->column = 0;
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

I used it in my getNum() function assuming it was correct.  It is as follows:

```
static float getNum(){
    char* tokenstr;
    tokenstr = malloc(tok.length * sizeof(char));

    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < tok.length; j++){
        tokenstr[j] = get_character(&loc);
    }
    match(T_LITERAL); /*match checks if the given token class is the same as the token
                        class of the token currently being parsed.  It then moves the
                        parser to the next token.*/
    printf("%f\n", atof(tokenstr));
    return atof(tokenstr);

}
```

Below is some additional information that is required to understand what is going on in the above functions.  These are details about some struct files which organize the input data.

In order to store and find tokens, three types of structs are used.  A line_t struct, a location_t struct, and a token_t struct.  The code for these are posted, but to summarize:

- Lines contain an array of characters (the input from that line of the
  input file), an int for the length of the line, an int that is the
  line number as a form of identification, and a pointer to the next
  line of input that was read into memory.
- Locations contain a pointer to a specific line, and an int that
  specifies a specific "column" of the line.
- Tokens contain an int for the length of the token, a location describing where the token    begins, and token class describing what kind of token it is for the parser.

Code for these structs:

```
typedef struct line {
    char * data;
    int line_num;
    int length; /* number of non-NUL characters == index of trailing NUL */
    struct line * next;
} line_t;

typedef struct {
    line_t *line;
    int column;
} location_t;

typedef struct {
    token_class tc;
    location_t location;
    int length;     /* length of token in characters (may span lines) */
} token_t;
```

Comment: Which parts of this code have you tested in isolation? You should build up from the simple to the complex, testing at every step. Failing that, you should at least give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to look at, since the problem may be in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework and Bison/Flex or Yacc/Lex are out of the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the default behavior intended is to extract a character and then advance to the next prior to returning.

Yet the function, if the line length is exceeded (or the collumn value isn't initialized to less than the line length) will *not* advance.

Try this:

```
if (loc->column >= loc->line->length) {
    loc->line = loc->line->next;
    loc->column = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

And make sure that the column location is properly initialized.

Personally, I would change the function to this:

```
int get_character(location_t *loc)
{
    int rtn = 0;

    if (loc->column < loc->line->length) {
        rtn = loc->line->data[loc->column++];
    }

    if (loc->column >= loc->line->length && loc->line->next) {
        loc->line = loc->line->next;
        loc->column = 0;
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

I'd also use unsigned values for the column and length, just to avoid the possibility of negative array indicies.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of potential problems with this code:

```
char* tokenstr;
tokenstr = malloc(tok.length * sizeof(char));

int j;
for(j = 0; j < tok.length; j++){
    tokenstr[j] = get_character(&loc);
}
match(T_LITERAL); /*match checks if the given token class is the same as the token
                    class of the token currently being parsed.  It then moves the
                    parser to the next token.*/
printf("%f\n", atof(tokenstr));
return atof(tokenstr);
```

You create space for a new token string `tokenstr`, you copy it  but you don't null terminate it after, nor is enough space allocated for a token plus the string terminator `\0`. And at the end there is a memory leak as tokenstr isn't `free`ed. I might consider a change to something like:

```
char* tokenstr;
float floatVal;

/* Make sure we have enough space including \0 to terminate string */
tokenstr = malloc((tok.length + 1) * sizeof(char));

int j;
for(j = 0; j < tok.length; j++){
    tokenstr[j] = get_character(&loc);
}
/* add the end of string \0 character */
tokenstr[j] = '\0'

match(T_LITERAL); /*match checks if the given token class is the same as the token
                    class of the token currently being parsed.  It then moves the
                    parser to the next token.*/

floatVal = atof(tokenstr);

/* Free up the `malloc`ed tokenstr as it is no longer needed */
free(tokenstr);

printf("%f\n", floatVal);
return floatVal;
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the holder variable's name to tokenstr and forgot to change it later in the code.  I edit the OP. Apologies for the confusion.